# Euler product over Landau primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, euler-product

**Is there anyone who can suggest me some papers on the following constant (Euler product over Landau primes)?**
$$\prod_{p\,=\,n^2+1}\,(1-p^{-1})=0.35588892...$$

Many thanks.

Comment: The density of such primes is conjectured by the random model for the primes (same heuristic as for the twin primes). The product converges (to a non-zero value) because $\sum_{p\le x,p-1\in Z^2} 1 = O(x^{1/2})$. But it is still unknown if there are infinitely such primes. Not sure what you hope more. It makes zero doubt that (if infinite) then the product doesn't have any simpler expression.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to rigorously prove estimates for this constant using sieve techniques, such as Brun's sieve. This would look very similar to proving bounds for $\sum 1/p$ where $p$ ranges across twin primes. I don't know of any place where this is done.

Comment: Hello! I've seen your last question about integers, which can be represented by positive ternary quadratic forms. You can find a proof [here](http://mathscinet.ru/files/Dikson.pdf) on page 69 theorem X.

Comment: @vitamind I thank you a lot!